# Wall following Robot without MicroController

Tags: proximity-sensor

I am trying to develop a Wall Following robot without using a micro controller. Is there any way I can maintain a fixed distance from the wall using Ultrasonic Sensor HC-SR04 without using Arduino.

Comment: well, to answer your question "is there any way?": yes, there is. Early heat-seeking missiles didn't use any digital components, and I'd argue your problem is easier. Why are you telling us about your PWM? That's nice, but does it have anything to do with your approach of doing this? **Why** would you want to do something that would very much beg for a microcontroller without a microcontroller? Are you trying to make your life hard?

Comment: Be aware that these sensors (like radar) have a **minimum** operating distance. To be clear: if your robot drives close to the wall, the sensor may give an incorrect or no result. And if your robot is not parallel to the wall, you may get an incorrect result too.

Comment: Can you touch the wall with a sensor? A rolling wheel on a spring loaded arm with a slide potentiometer?

Comment: From the datasheet: "time of high output IO duration is
the time from sending ultrasonic to returning." With a RC (resistor-capacitor) circuit you can use this duration to either turn on or off some transistor switch. HTH.

Answer (score 1):

if the PWM frequency is fixed you can convert the PWM signal to DC using a low-pass filter and then compare that with a constant voltage

The result can be used to steer the robot. or possibly fed straight to a PWM sensing servo

Comment: can you clarify how the result can be fed into the servo

Comment: the servo wants PWM puses of a about a millisecond, just arrange that.  http://www.ee.ic.ac.uk/pcheung/teaching/DE1_EE/stores/sg90_datasheet.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Use LED pulsed at 10KHz, shining on the wall. Monitor the return photons using phototransistor. The closer the wall (assume white specular reflection), the more photons into the phototransistor, and the higher the collecter current. Use the collecter current to control PWM timing.

Comment: thanks. I'll try this method also. but I'm looking for a method which uses SONAR sensor